# Deployment and Timer

Tags: c#, timer, .net-micro-framework

I have 2 questions.

1. I am using the Netdunio Plus 2 and upgraded to the latest firmware / .NET Micro Framework 4.3 and the deployment works about 30% of the time. Are there known deployment issues with this version of the framework? I am almost tempted to return to version 4.2 or earlier.
2. I am investigating different high precision timers, I have read about using the PWM tied to an IO to get very deterministic results for timing, are there any other approaches to getting a high precision timer?

I am currently using this for my timer, which I found on here

```
  ticks = Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks;
  //Do some work...
  while((Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks - ticks) < DelayTicks);
```

Comment: "2 unrelated questions" should be two separate questions in SO.

Comment: Removing the word "unrelated" doesn't change the fact that your questions shouldn't be grouped together

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I've found it best to run the program with the USB unplugged, and wait for it to print out 
`Iteration 1....
 Iteration 2....`

And then plug in the netduino (within 5 seconds). You'll have a much higher success rate.

Question 2:

[Check out the responses in netduino's forum here](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/2537-how-do-i-create-a-high-resolution-timer-for-netduino-plus/)